# Infinite Limits Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $$lim_n(n^2-5n+1)=∞$$
I understand the concept.  Given M>0 and N>0 there exist an n>N that implies $(n^2-5n+1)>M.$

How do I go about showing that $(n^2-5n+1)>M?$

Comment: Hint: for $n \geq 6$, $n^2 \geq 6n$, so that $n^2-5n+1 > n+1$.

Comment: Prove that the inequality $n^2 - 5n + 1 - M > 0$ has always solution? just study $\Delta = 25 - 4(1 - M) \geq 0 \forall M \geq 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking any $M > 0$, we have
$$
n^{2} - 5n+1 > n^{2} - 5n = n(n-5) > M
$$
if $n > M+5$,
so taking $N := \lceil M+5 \rceil $ suffices.

Comment: I follow this until going from n(n-5)>M to n>M+5.

Comment: I get this one now. Is there something in general that I should look for in order to answer more of these?

Comment: @DavidHouse: I edited my answer to get rid of the sloppy "$N := M+5$".

Comment: If $n > M+5$ then $n(n-5) > M^{2} + 5M > M$.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show that the sequence is unbounded, then you could show that there exists an $n_0$ such that $\forall n>n_0$
$$
n^2-5n+1>n \Leftrightarrow n^2>6n-1
$$
which is true for $n_0=6$. Now since $n$ goes to infinity so must $n^2-5n+1$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

This of course means that it suffices to show that for any given but fixed $M$ we have can find an $n_M$ such that $\forall n>n_M$ we have
$$
n>M
$$
this is clearly the case for $n_M:=\lceil M \rceil$.